# Is *th* ever used not as a thorn outside of portmanteaus?

Tags: pronunciation

Pretty much every occurrence of *th* I can think of see are pronounced as */θ/* or very similar sounds (sometimes slightly closer to *f* or *s*).

Still, does *th* appear in any English word pronounced as two distinct phonemes, */th/* ? I can think of some portmanteaus where the first word ends with *t* and the other begins with *h* (e.g. "pothead") but does it ever appear *naturally* as that pair of phonemes in words, not brought together as part of portmanteaus or blends?

Comment: Other than the hothouses it is difficult to think of any.

Comment: other portmanteaus include knighthood, lighthouse, apartheid

Comment: Funnily enough, I invariably pronounce apartheid with a th ;)

Comment: Aren't you using "portmanteaus" to describe compounds?

Comment: @MSalters: Possibly compounds *too*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "Theresa" pronunced with the plosive /t/?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/368742/why-is-theresa-pronunced-with-the-plosive-t) That other question is actually younger, but has better answers IMO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the geographical names: Thames, Thame, Theale (although local opinion appears to be divided on that one), Thailand, Lesotho.

In the names "Thomas", "Thomson", "Esther".

The only common noun, i.e. not a proper noun, I can think of is "thyme".

Answer (score 1):

The river Thames, Thailand, [thalweg](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thalweg) (geographical term, although sometimes spelled talweg), Theresa are some.